# Telerik RadDocking panels does not get resized with the Main framework windows on window restore

Tags: wpf, telerik, prism

We are using Telerik RadDocking control within our main framework window. The RadDocking contains two RadSplitContainers and each container has a RadPaneGroup with one Rad panel to Display Data. The Application is created using Prism with MEF Container using MVVM design Pattern.

Description: 
The left Container is Docked Permanently so that it cannon float/Auto hide/Close. This container is set to a minimum Width and Height. As there is no Maximum Width this container is able to fill in available space in the Main Framework Window (e.g. when the panel in the right container is undocked to float the left container takes all the framework window).
The Right Container is able to Float/Auto Hide/Close. This Container is also set to a minimum Width and Height.

Issue 1:
with the Main framework window on full screen if the right Container is moved to the extreme right to its minimum Width and the main framework window is restored/resized the containers doesn't get resize to the main framework window.  This causes the Right docked container and some portion of left docked container to be dragged out of the main framework window and is not visible. To make the right container visible either i need to resize the main framework window to a bigger size or maximise the Main framework window to full screen. 
Is there a way to resize the container according to the main framework windows size?  so that both the containers with panel are visible in any scenario whether right docked container is moved to extreme right to its minimum width or left docked container is moved to extreme left to it minimum width.
I have tried the proportional stack panel with relative width set to both containers but it gives the same issue as above.

```
<telerik:RadDocking x:Name="SiteHomeDockingControl" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1" HasDocumentHost="False" 
                    PreviewShowCompass="SiteHomeDockingControl_PreviewShowCompass"  > 

                <telerik:RadSplitContainer telerik:RadDocking.SerializationTag="RadSplitContainerSites" BorderThickness="0"  
                MinWidth="305" MinHeight="305"  telerik:DockingPanel.InitialSize="1000,500"> 
                    <telerik:RadPaneGroup x:Name="RadPaneGroupSites" telerik:RadDocking.SerializationTag="RadPaneGroupSites" BorderThickness="0"> 
                        <telerik:RadPane PaneHeaderVisibility="Collapsed" CanUserClose="False" CanFloat="False" CanUserPin="False" 
                                             telerik:RadDocking.SerializationTag="RadPaneSites" > 
                            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"> 
                                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="35,15,15,15"> 
                                <TextBlock Text="Just an example Docked Pane 1."/> 
                                </Grid> 
                            </ScrollViewer> 
                        </telerik:RadPane> 
                    </telerik:RadPaneGroup> 
                </telerik:RadSplitContainer> 

                <telerik:RadSplitContainer InitialPosition="DockedRight" telerik:RadDocking.SerializationTag="RadSplitContainerPlantHierarchies"
                MinWidth="305" MinHeight="305" telerik:DockingPanel.InitialSize="400,500"> 
                    <telerik:RadPaneGroup telerik:RadDocking.SerializationTag="RadPaneGroupPlantHierarchies"> 
                        <telerik:RadPane telerik:RadDocking.SerializationTag="RadPanePlantHierarchies" Header="Plant Hierarchies"
                        IsHidden="{Binding DataContext.HidePlantHierarchies, ElementName=SiteHomeDockingControl, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"> 
                            <Grid> 
                            <TextBlock Text="Just an example Docked Pane 2."/> 
                            </Grid> 
                        </telerik:RadPane> 
                    </telerik:RadPaneGroup> 
                </telerik:RadSplitContainer> 

</telerik:RadDocking>
```